# How do i run enketo-express on Ubuntu?

Tags: docker, nginx, command-line, docker-compose, ubuntu-14.04

After setup of [enketo express](https://github.com/kobotoolbox/enketo-express), When i run enketo-express using command "**docker-compose up -d**" on an ubuntu server, it shows an below error related to nginx

ERROR: for docker_nginx_1  Cannot start service nginx: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint docker_nginx_1 (7c414e255d50f42a0fa14d07c0b0d29125f666d77e55e5eb4437e43e3e4d9454): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use'

ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint docker_nginx_1 (7c414e255d50f42a0fa14d07c0b0d29125f666d77e55e5eb4437e43e3e4d9454): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use'

Answer (score 1):

By default 80 port is used by the apache service on ubuntu server. This means you need to change your port.
Just try to Bind port 8081 of your ubuntu with the port 80 of the container. For this use this command,

`$ run docker run -d -p 8081:80 --name webserver nginx`

This creates the link you need to access it at http://localhost:8081/

Note- Change port in "setup/docker/docker-compose.yml" file. eg: 80:80 to 8081:80

Answer (score 0):

It's because something is already running on port 80 on the host machine.

View which process it is, get the PID -

`$ lsof -i:80`
`$ netstat -tulnap | grep :80`

Kill the process -

`$ kill -9 $PID`

Try now & you will be good -

`$ docker-compose up -d`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have tried this but, it's showing the same.

Comment: `netstat -tulnap | grep :80` I get: `netstat: option requires an argument -- p`